# In Clojure, passing number with leading 0s to str causes strange behavior. What feature is this?

Tags: string, clojure, output, read-eval-print-loop

So, I accidentally figured this out while playing around with some strings.

```clj
(str 111) => "111"
(str 0111) => "73"
```

What is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers prefixed with `0` are [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal):

```
0111
=> 73
```

Numbers prefixed with `0x` are [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal):

```
0x111
=> 273
```

Numbers prefixed with `Xr`, where X is number from 2 to 36, have that radix:

```
2r111
=> 7
```

If you want to pad number with zeros, see [`format`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/format) or [`cl-format`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format):

```
(format "%04d" 111)
=> "0111"

(clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~4,'0d" 111)
=> "0111"
```

Comment: You're very kind. I appreciate it. Figured it was a different base system, but I couldn't figure out which one.

Comment: Not specific to Clojure, btw -- the octal and hex conventions in particular are quite popular (covered by C, and thus most other languages that take their cues from it).

Comment: Yes, I went and checked this with other languages right after the answer came in. I figured it sounded to generic for it to be clojure specific. In retrospect, I once learned this, but forgot it because of how rare I used it. Good to remember though.